# Why am I unable to insert anything in webstorm project?

Tags: webstorm

I am using Macbook Pro and installed webstorm and created an empty project. In that project I added a new HTML file. When I try to insert a new row inside to body to add  tag but I can't edit anything. I thought the file might be somehow read only but to my surprise I can delete characters from the file but I can not add anything to it. Is there something am I doing wrong? Just for testing I open text editor and I am able to add delete and other things so it is not the Mac but something in Webstorm. Does anyone know why this behaviour happens?

Thanks

2014-01-23 22:10:09,184 [2285624]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - JetBrains WebStorm 6.0.2  Build #WS-129.664 
2014-01-23 22:10:09,184 [2285624]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - JDK: 1.6.0_65 
2014-01-23 22:10:09,184 [2285624]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2014-01-23 22:10:09,184 [2285624]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - Vendor: Apple Inc. 
2014-01-23 22:10:09,184 [2285624]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - OS: Mac OS X 
2014-01-23 22:10:09,184 [2285624]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - Last Action: MarkAsOriginalTypeAction 
2014-01-23 22:10:09,184 [2285624]  ERROR - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - update failed for AnAction with ID=RunCoverage 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.browsers.WebBrowserService.getUrlToOpen(Lcom/intellij/psi/PsiElement;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.intellij.javascript.debugger.execution.JavaScriptDebugConfigurationProducer.createConfigurationByLocation(JavaScriptDebugConfigurationProducer.java:85)
    at com.intellij.javascript.debugger.execution.JavaScriptDebugConfigurationProducer.createConfigurationByElement(JavaScriptDebugConfigurationProducer.java:38)
    at com.intellij.execution.junit.RuntimeConfigurationProducer.createProducer(RuntimeConfigurationProducer.java:55)
    at com.intellij.execution.actions.PreferredProducerFind.findPreferredProducers(PreferredProducerFind.java:62)

Comment: 1) If you have installed any 3rd party plugins (not bundled ones) please disable them. 2) Please check (or attach here somehow) your `idea.log` for additional details / hints (Help | Show Log in...)

Comment: yes there are errors, I added the last error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have AngularJS plugin installed? if yes, check if the kotlin-runtime.jar exists in ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/WebStorm7/angularjs-plugin/lib. if it's not there, remove the  angularjs plugin and reinstall it from the repository (Preferences/Plugins, Browse repositories...) - this should solve the  problem.